# can't run netbeans as a normal user!

Tags: 13.04, netbeans, jvm

I have installed netbeans 7.3.1 on ubuntu 13.04 by running the "netbeans-7.3.1-linux.sh" file downloaded from netbeans.org 
the problem is whenever I run netbeans as normal user it stuck on loading modules and then exits and no error is displaying 
I have tried to run it by command line and get the following messages

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000, pid=8810, tid=2168195904

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b100) (build 1.8.0-ea-b100)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.0-b42 mixed mode linux-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x00000000

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/nmaybar/hs_err_pid8810.log
[thread -2088768704 also had an error]

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/nbexec: line 610:  8810 Aborted                 (core dumped) "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" -Djdk.home="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" -classpath "/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/boot.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar" -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root="/home/nmaybar/.netbeans" -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy="DIRECT" -Dnetbeans.system_http_non_proxy_hosts="" -Dnetbeans.dirs="/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/nb:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/ergonomics:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/ide:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/java:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/apisupport:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/webcommon:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/websvccommon:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/enterprise:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/mobility:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/profiler:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/python:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/php:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/identity:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/harness:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/cnd:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/dlight:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/groovy:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/extra:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/javacard:/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/javafx:" -Dnetbeans.home="/home/nmaybar/netbeans-7.3.1/platform" '-Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade' '-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense' '-XX:MaxPermSize=384m' '-Xmx768m' '-client' '-Xss2m' '-Xms32m' '-XX:PermSize=32m' '-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true' '-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true' '-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true' '-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true' '-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true' -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/home/nmaybar/.netbeans/7.3.1/var/log/heapdump.hprof" org.netbeans.Main --userdir "/home/nmaybar/.netbeans/7.3.1" "--cachedir" "/home/nmaybar/.cache/netbeans/7.3.1" "--branding" "nb" 0<&0
nmaybar@nmaybar-SVS13118GAB:~$ sudo netbeans-7.3.1/bin/netbeans 
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
```

But When I run netbeans as root using sudo command it works.

so what is the problem?

thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: What is the content of `/home/nmaybar/hs_err_pid8810.log`?

Comment: I have the same problem running NetBeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 13.04.  At the top, my "hs_error" file says:

`# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f857747f880, pid=4627, tid=140211684067072
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 13.04, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.13.04.2
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f857747f880
[error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xb]`