# Installing netbeans on default user doesn't work but on root does

Tags: software-installation, java, netbeans

I'm trying to install latest netbeans but installing on normal user results with modern looking gui which freezes after early configuration progress bar.

Running same installer with sudo results in different looking gui which works well, but I don't want to run netbeans on root every time.

This is how it looks:
[image]

- Why can't I install netbeans as normal user?
- What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: The GUI is different because the theme for `root` and your user is different. As for crashing when run normally (i.e. no root), see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332885/cant-run-netbeans-as-a-normal-user?rq=1).

Comment: @Bharadwaj Raju, yes but I can't even install it

Comment: While the different GUI issue is easily solved (run System Settings as root and select theme of choice), you'll want the crash issue as a separate question.

Comment: Well, different gui isn't a big deal so I've just edited the title and content to fit our answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found solution on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1520743

If you have a similar problem running openjdk 7 or 8 you need to go to:

`/etc/java-8-openjdk/` <-- different for different openjdk versions
and edit accessibility.properties. Comment out:

`assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper`
 by placing # before this line

Answer (score 1):

After installing as root I had a similar problem.  I could run as root, but running as a normal user would crash.  Resetting/removing the user directories solved it:

`sudo rm -rf /home/[user]/.netbeans /home/[user]/.cache/netbeans`